# Table Per Type data retrieval

Tags: sql, database, entity-framework, join

I have followed multiple articles, which mostly use Entity Framework query to show how to retrieve data. However, if you consider the table structure below:

[image: Table Per Type sample]

If I want to find a detail of the car with ID 2 using just plain SQL, should I use the ID to look for a match in all inherited tables ("Used Car" and "New Car" in this example)?

Does it not cause a full scan of "Used Car" table before I find it in the "New Car" table? Or is there a way I could know that I have to go to "New Car" table directly?

Or is my assumption of how a Table-Per-Type design is wrong?

Comment: There is no way with TPT to know directly which "derived" table contains the data for a specific ID. The information is always extracted with joins. See **TPT Considerations** section in [Inheritance with EF Code First: Part 2 – Table per Type (TPT)](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt)

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks. For 1 level inheritance where I have 1 base table and say 10 immediate child table, will the performance be a problem? I think performance can be a challenge if I have multiple levels of inheritance. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: IMO, yes. I would recommend you reading the whole series from the link, the author explains in details all 3 EF inheritance strategies with pros and cons of each (none is ideal).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wanted to find the year, you might do:

```
select c.*, coalesce(uc.year, nc.year) as year,
       (case when uc.id is not null then 'Used' else 'New' end) as which
from car c left join
     usedcar uc
     on c.id = uc.id left join
     newcar nc
     on c.id = nc.id
where c.id = 2;
```

You should declare `id` as a primary key in all tables (although I would name it `carId`).  Then no scan is going to be done.  Just index lookups.

In other words, your design is fine.  You might want various constraints to ensure that a car is new or used, but not both.

Comment: Thank you very much, Can you please explain what this part of query does:    "coalesce(uc.year, nc.year) as year,
       (case when uc.id is not null then 'Used' else 'New' end) as which" and why there are 2 left joins?

Comment: Don't worry, I got it. And again thanks for the help.